# How to make a WebView only take up the height of its content?

Tags: .net, xaml, webview, maui

I am porting a very simple Xamarin.Forms application to .NET MAUI (native, not Blazor Hybrid) for mobile and Windows. One page consists just of a `WebView` taking up all of the viewport as well as a normally transparent `ProgressBar` laid on top of it (thus the `AbsoluteLayout`) to indicate the loading process when navigating inside of the WebView.

```xml
<AbsoluteLayout x:Name="AbsoluteLayoutFrame" Padding="0" Margin="0">
    <RefreshView x:Name="RefreshView" RefreshColor="#2680ff"
                 AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                 AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
                 Margin="0">
        <ScrollView x:Name="WebScrollView">
            <WebView x:Name="DigifaiWebView" Margin="0"
                     VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                     Navigating="OnNavigating"
                     Navigated="OnNavigated"/>
        </ScrollView>
    </RefreshView>
    ...
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

I use a RefreshView to trigger a reload of the page in the WebView on a swipe-down gesture.

Initially, WebView was a direct child of the RefreshView (which works well on Android), however, [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/refreshview?view=net-maui-8.0) tell me that the child of a RefreshView must be a scrollable element. Sure enough, without it the webview on windows shows a "dead" reload icon and swallows any click events on the top ~150px of the webview.

[image: broken WebView on desktop without ScrollView]

Therefore, I added a `ScrollView` as instructed by the docs. This works great on Windows, but now I have another problem on Android: With the current setup, the WebView on Android takes up way more space in height than it actually needs (-> multiple screens of pure white when scrolling down).

[image: WebView does not stop]

I played a lot with XAML properties like `VerticalOptions` or `Height` (on the WebView and on the ScrollView), but I just can't get the WebView to shrink down to the size of its HTML content. As I said, the current XAML works perfectly on Windows (even when navigating to much shorter subpages in the Webview), but it leaves these massive amounts of whitespace on Android.
Without the ScrollView, it's pretty much the other way round.

How do I resolve this issue? Why does the page on Android even take up so much useless space?

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't use unrestrained layouts or content in a ScrollView. Setting a ScrollView's content's HeightRequest to `Fill` or `FillAndExpand` doesn't provide any constraints for the content, meaning that it could technically be infinite. Secondly, the `*AndExpand` options are deprecated in MAUI and shouldn't be used anymore. Have you tried wrapping the `WebView` in a Grid?

Comment: Ok, thank you, I didn't know AndExpand is deprecated. I also tried using VerticalOptions="Start" for both the WebView and/or the ScrollView though.

Yes, I tried wrapping it in a Grid and just tested it again - same outcome.

Comment: Update: Using `VerticalOptions="Start"` stops the overflow on Android but appears to render the WebView on windows with a height of zero (I cannot see it anymore). Also, the WebView does not resize when I navigate to a subpage that is shorter. I have already been at this stage some hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

Fyi, I ended up creating a workaround for the problem by building the affected part of the UI in code-behind dynamically based on the target platform using compiler directives.

```cs
    private readonly WebView DigifaiWebView = new WebView();

    public View()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        RefreshView.Command = RefreshCommand;

        DigifaiWebView.Navigating += OnNavigating;
        DigifaiWebView.Navigated += OnNavigated;
        DigifaiWebView.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill;
        DigifaiWebView.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill;

#if ANDROID
        RefreshView.Content = DigifaiWebView;
#else
        DigifaiWebView.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill;
        ScrollView scrollView = new();
        scrollView.Content = DigifaiWebView;
        RefreshView.Content = scrollView; 
#endif
        ...
    }
```

However, it still doesn't feel right, as the [MAUI docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/refreshview?view=net-maui-8.0) claim a RefreshView MUST contain a scrollable element as its direct child and WebView does not seem to be counted as such (or is it on Android?).

If you have any better idea how to fix this or suspect this is a bug within .NET MAUI, please feel free to tell me.